# How to use npm link?

Tags: ionic-framework, npm-link

I have a module, let call it `contact_us`, that I have linked it to my ionic project. I could successfully link the module and see it in my app, but when I modify the `contact_us` module, the changes are not reflected in my project.

Here is what I've done:

1. In the `contact_us` module:

```
 npm link
```

2. In the project:

```
npm link contact_us
ionic cap build android
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found how to update the link.
In your module directory, i.e., contact_us, do:

```
npm run build
cd /dist/contact_us
npm link
ng build --watch
```

Then in the you project directory:

```
npm link contact_us
ionic cap build android
```